# Is there any way of unregister a longlistmultiselector from an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, longlistselector

I have an app with a list of photos on an ObservableCollection.  I'm using that list as source for longlistmultiselectos on diferent views.

Now I realize that the views that use that ObservableCollection are not garbage collected and each time the user navigates to a new view it is created again despite it is on memory or not.

I think it is because the ObservableCollection is keeping a reference to the view.

How can I broke that reference?  Is there another aproach to this problem.

Thank you very much.  Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ItemSource property of the LongListMultiSelector to null will break this cycle.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to work.  How can I check if it works?

Comment: Add a destructor to the view, and verify that it is called. You may have other leaks. Also note that objects won't get GC'd immediately, or often at all until there is memory pressure.